# using getElementById within popup opened by magnificPopup fails when trying access popup element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

Using getElementById fails, cause it tries to find the element with id "in" in the father HTML. How to get content of input element "id" from within the popup?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/magnific-popup.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="someid">Open popup</button>

<script>
    $('#someid').magnificPopup({
                                          items: {
                                              src:  
                                                    '<div class="white-popup"><br>\
                                                    <input id="in" type="text" placeholder="content">\
                                                    <a href=document.getElementById('in')>Click</a>',

                                              type: 'inline'
                                          }
                           });  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation, like this

## 1

```
$('#someid').magnificPopup({
  items: {
    src: [
        '<div class="white-popup"><br>',
        '<input id="in" type="text" placeholder="content">',
        '<a href="#">Click</a></div>'
    ].join(),
    
    type: 'inline'
  }
});

$('body').on('click', '.white-popup > a', function () {
  alert($(this).siblings('#in').val());
})
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/votam/1/](http://jsbin.com/votam/1/edit?js,output)

## 2 or

```
$('#someid').magnificPopup({
  items: {
    src: [
        '<div class="white-popup"><br>',
        '<input id="in" type="text" placeholder="content">',
        '<a href="javascript:alert(document.getElementById(\'in\').value);">Click</a></div>'
    ].join(),
    
    type: 'inline'
  }
});
```

DEMO: [http://jsbin.com/votam/2/](http://jsbin.com/votam/2/edit?js,output)

## 3

```
$('#someid').magnificPopup({
  items: {
    src: [
        '<div class="white-popup"><br>',
        '<input id="in" type="text" placeholder="content">',
        '<a href="url?arg1=\'arg1\'&arg2=" onclick="this.href = this.href + document.getElementById(\'in\').value ">Click</a></div>'
    ].join(),
    
    type: 'inline'
  }
});
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/votam/3/edit](http://jsbin.com/votam/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks. However when trying to use document.getElementById(\'in\').value in URL it's considered as string as in <a href='url?arg1='arg1'&arg2=document.getElementById(\'in\').value>Click</a>\